# Angular 7 : Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am implementing a checkbox functionality in Angular 7. Checking unchecking the checkbox filters the records. The checkbox works fine and triggers the concerned method. I am having issue with filtering the record. I need to filter records that have InvestmentStatusId = 1. I am getting error cannot read
Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.Could somebody tell me what is wrong with my filter.

JSON - this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel

```
 [
  {
    "Description": "Class B",
    "AuditSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "Id": 11166,
    "FundId": 5508,
    "FundClassType": 1,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 45,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": null,
    "LockupTypeName": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": null,
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": 3,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": null,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": null,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": "12 M,0.03|",
    "LockupComments": null,
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": false,
    "GateInvestorPct": null,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": null,
    "IntialProceeds": null,
    "PaymentInDays": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "HoldbackPercentage": null,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": null,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": null,
    "HighWaterMarkId": null,
    "HighWaterMarkName": null,
    "HurdleRate": false,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": null,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": false,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": null,
    "FeeComments": null,
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 0
  },
  {
    "Description": "Class A",
    "AuditSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "Id": 11167,
    "FundId": 5508,
    "FundClassType": 1,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 45,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": null,
    "LockupTypeName": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": null,
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": 3,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": null,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": null,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": "12 M,0.03|",
    "LockupComments": null,
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": false,
    "GateInvestorPct": null,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": null,
    "IntialProceeds": null,
    "PaymentInDays": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "HoldbackPercentage": null,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": null,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": null,
    "HighWaterMarkId": null,
    "HighWaterMarkName": null,
    "HurdleRate": false,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": null,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": false,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": null,
    "FeeComments": null,
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 0
  },
  {
    "Description": "Class B",
    "AuditSummary": "rmenon May 29, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "Id": 28414,
    "FundId": 5508,
    "FundClassType": 4,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 45,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": null,
    "LockupTypeName": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": null,
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": 3,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": null,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": null,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": "12 M,0.03|",
    "LockupComments": null,
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": false,
    "GateInvestorPct": null,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": null,
    "IntialProceeds": null,
    "PaymentInDays": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "HoldbackPercentage": null,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": null,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": null,
    "HighWaterMarkId": null,
    "HighWaterMarkName": null,
    "HurdleRate": false,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": null,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": false,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": null,
    "FeeComments": null,
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 0
  },
  {
    "Description": "Class D",
    "AuditSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "Id": 13714,
    "FundId": 237146,
    "FundClassType": 3,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 45,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": null,
    "LockupTypeName": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": null,
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": null,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": null,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": null,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": null,
    "LockupComments": null,
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": false,
    "GateInvestorPct": null,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": null,
    "IntialProceeds": null,
    "PaymentInDays": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "HoldbackPercentage": null,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": null,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": null,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": null,
    "HighWaterMarkId": null,
    "HighWaterMarkName": null,
    "HurdleRate": false,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": null,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": false,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": null,
    "FeeComments": null,
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 0
  },
  {
    "Description": "Class B",
    "AuditSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "dmukerji Mar 11, 2019",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "Id": 13717,
    "FundId": 237146,
    "FundClassType": 3,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 46,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": 5,
    "LockupTypeName": "No Lock",
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": null,
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": 0,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": null,
    "LockupComments": "In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.",
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": false,
    "GateInvestorPct": 0,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": 0,
    "IntialProceeds": 100,
    "PaymentInDays": 30,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "HoldbackPercentage": 0,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": 0,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": 30,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": 7,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": "Yearly",
    "HighWaterMarkId": 1,
    "HighWaterMarkName": "Standard",
    "HurdleRate": false,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": 0,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": false,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": 1,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": "Management Fee",
    "FeeComments": "New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.",
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 1
  },
  {
    "Description": "Class A",
    "AuditSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "dmukerji Mar 11, 2019",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "rmenon May 28, 2019",
    "Id": 13713,
    "FundId": 237146,
    "FundClassType": 3,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 46,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": 5,
    "LockupTypeName": "No Lock",
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": null,
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": 0,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": null,
    "LockupComments": "In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.",
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": true,
    "GateInvestorPct": 0,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": 0,
    "IntialProceeds": 100,
    "PaymentInDays": 30,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "HoldbackPercentage": 0,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": 0,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": 30,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": 7,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": "Yearly",
    "HighWaterMarkId": 1,
    "HighWaterMarkName": "Standard",
    "HurdleRate": true,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": 0,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": true,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": 1,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": "Management Fee",
    "FeeComments": "New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.",
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 1
  },
  {
    "Description": "Class B1",
    "AuditSummary": "kweigand Feb 19, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "kweigand Feb 19, 2019",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "fblack Nov 21, 2018",
    "Id": 13716,
    "FundId": 237146,
    "FundClassType": 3,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 46,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": 5,
    "LockupTypeName": "No Lock",
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": 22,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": "72",
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": 0,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": null,
    "LockupComments": "In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.",
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": false,
    "GateInvestorPct": 0,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": 0,
    "IntialProceeds": 100,
    "PaymentInDays": 30,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "HoldbackPercentage": 0,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": 0,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": 30,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": 7,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": "Yearly",
    "HighWaterMarkId": 1,
    "HighWaterMarkName": "Standard",
    "HurdleRate": false,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": 0,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": false,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": 1,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": "Management Fee",
    "FeeComments": "New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.",
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 0
  },
  {
    "Description": "Class C",
    "AuditSummary": "kweigand Feb 19, 2019",
    "FeesReviewSummary": "kweigand Feb 19, 2019",
    "TermsReviewSummary": "fblack Nov 21, 2018",
    "Id": 13715,
    "FundId": 237146,
    "FundClassType": 3,
    "CurrencyId": null,
    "PrimaryCurrencyName": null,
    "OtherCurrencyName": null,
    "ManagerStrategyId": null,
    "ManagerStrategyName": null,
    "SubVotingId": null,
    "SubVotingName": null,
    "SubHotIssueId": null,
    "SubHotIssueName": null,
    "RedsFrqncyId": 5,
    "RedsFrqncyName": "Quarterly",
    "RedsNoticeDays": 46,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "NoticeTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "LockupTypeId": 5,
    "LockupTypeName": "No Lock",
    "HardDurationMonthsId": null,
    "HardDurationMonthsName": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsId": null,
    "SoftDurationMonthsName": null,
    "LockupFees0To12Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees12To24Pct": 0,
    "LockupFees24To36Pct": 0,
    "WebfolioRedsFee": null,
    "LockupComments": "In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.",
    "ApplyGateDecliningBalance": false,
    "GateInvestorPct": 0,
    "GateSourceId": null,
    "GateSourceName": null,
    "GateFundClassPct": 0,
    "IntialProceeds": 100,
    "PaymentInDays": 30,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysId": 2,
    "PaymentTypeOfDaysName": "Calendar",
    "HoldbackPercentage": 0,
    "HoldbackPayment": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysId": null,
    "HoldbackTypeOfDaysName": null,
    "ManagementFeeRate": 0,
    "IncentiveFeeRate": 30,
    "RealizationFrequencyId": 7,
    "RealizationFrequencyName": "Yearly",
    "HighWaterMarkId": 1,
    "HighWaterMarkName": "Standard",
    "HurdleRate": false,
    "HurdleRateBasisId": null,
    "HurdleRateBasisName": null,
    "HurdleRatePct": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexId": null,
    "HurdleRateIndexName": null,
    "PreferredReturnRatePct": 0,
    "GpCatchUp": null,
    "PreferredReturnComments": null,
    "Clawback": false,
    "ClawbackPercentage": null,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": 1,
    "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": "Management Fee",
    "FeeComments": "New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.",
    "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
    "InvestmentStatusId": 0
  }
]
```

Code

```
this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel.forEach(legalFunDetail=> {
                    legalFunDetail.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel = legalFunDetail.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel
                       // .reduce((prev, next) => prev = prev.concat(next), [])
                        .filter(obj => obj.InvestmentStatusId === 1);
                });
```

Comment: `legalFunDetail.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel` is undefined. There is no `LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel` field in the `this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel` array items.

Comment: I believe you need to filter `this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel` directly: `this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel.filter(obj => obj.InvestmentStatusId === 1)`